# The data format for post in urllib2.Request

Tags: python

What should data look like before data encoding in:
`urllib2.Request(someurl,data)`  I tried `[('name1','value1'),('name2','value2'),...]`but not work.:(

EDIT:
I made a log in the program and recorded the value of `urllib.urlencode(data)`:

```
content=%E5%8F%91%E5%B8%83%E4%BA%86%E4%B8%80%E4%B8%AA%E6%96%B0%E4%B8%BB%E9%A2%98%EF%BC%9A%3Ca+href%3D%27http%3A%2F%2Fbbs.jianshe99.com%2Fforum-5-195%2Ftopic-448618.html%27+target%3D%27_blank%27%3E+fsdfdsf%3C%2Fa%3E
```

then post it to a php script which is

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

but always get a response as:

```
array()
```

Comment: Dictionary style works fine.I should have known that!

Comment: Tagged with python, but it's PHP?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*data* may be a **string** specifying additional data to send to the server, or `None` if no such data is needed. Currently HTTP requests are the only ones that use *data*; the HTTP request will be a POST instead of a GET when the *data* parameter is provided. *data* should be a **buffer** in the standard *application/x-www-form-urlencoded* format. The [urllib.urlencode()](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode)  function takes a mapping or sequence of 2-tuples and returns a string in this format.

### See Also

- [urllib2.Request](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.Request)

Comment: Thanks for your instruction.And I updated my question,can you give me a further suggestion?

Comment: I can't say I can, you've switched across to an entirely new question and language. PHP is strictly not in my list of interests :)